# How to Fetch Whatsapp public profile of unknown number if it exist like Photo, Status, last seen in real time?

Tags: android, appium, whatsapp, business-intelligence, user-profile

**Use-case**: Sending personalised message to the potential leads.

**Is this possible?**
Companies like [Seon](https://seon.io/) is able to fetch attributes like account exist check, last seen, photo graph, status etc in realtime

**What I am able to achieve:**

In Real Time: I am able to check whether contact exist or not using [Whatsapp contact API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/reference/contacts)

```
POST /v1/contacts
{
  "blocking": "wait" | "no_wait",
  "contacts": [
    "16315551000",
    "+1 631 555 1001",
    "6315551002",
    "+1 (631) 555-1004",
    "1-631-555-1005"
  ],
  "force_check": false | true
}
```

Non Real Time:
I was to fetch account exist check, last seen, photo graph, status via [appium](https://appium.io/) (test automation framework)

**Problem with my solution:**

1. It is costly to scale as renting emulator on cloud is very costly
2. It is not real time.(by real time I mean getting solution in less than 2-4 sec)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no option/support in [WhatsApp Business API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/) to get the user's information by providing a phone number.

> *In Real Time: I am able to check whether contact exist or not using [Whatsapp contact API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/reference/contacts)*

With the contacts node you can:

> - Verify that a phone number in your database belongs to a valid WhatsApp account. You must ensure that the status is valid before you can message a user.
> - Get the WhatsApp ID for a phone number. WhatsApp IDs are needed to send messages and user notifications.